# New browser opens for every feature being executed - WATIR

Tags: selenium, firefox, cucumber, watir, gherkin

We are using the Selenium Cucumber framework with Watir.

We have split one scenario into different features and all these features needs to run on one browser to complete the scenario.

Currently 1 feature completes and then the browser is closed and then a new instance of Firefox is opened; not preserving the state of the previous instance.

For our tests to run effectively, we need these features to be completed on the same browser instance.

How do we prevent a new browser instance open after each feature has been executed?

Here is our test structure:

```
W2.1.1-Set_Project_Information.feature
W2.1.2-Select_Shotlist.feature
W2.1.3-Flag_shotlist_requiring_physical_inspection.feature
W2.1.4-Select_applicable_shotlist_task.feature
W2.1.5-Record_Primary_Applicant.feature
```

My `env.rb`:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'rspec'

browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox

Before do
#browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
@browser = browser
@browser.goto "https://test.branzartisan.com"
@browser.window.maximize
sleep(5)
puts "###Browser Invoke###"
end

After do |scenario|
@browser.cookies.clear
  @browser.refresh
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this issue was removing the `before do` block from the `env.rb` file.

This prevented the invoking of a new Firefox instance before each scenario.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is the same as here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17624188/4072371

That being said, I feel obligated to point out that ideally you can make your tests independent of each other.